# Exporting const to another file in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a table component that is reusable with different column props. My app uses the component several times, and many times I use the same columns but not all. So I'm trying to export my "const columns = ..." to a separate file. the problem is it can't be a pure function, because I'm using useMemo and numeral... how can I move the my columns to a separate file so they can be accessed by multiple tables or defined separately if needed?

```
//App.js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'
import numeral from "numeral";
import makeData from './makeData'



function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'COH',
            accessor: 'age',
            Cell: (props) => (
                <div className="color1">
                {numeral(props.value).format("$0,0.000")}
                </div>
        ),
          },
          {
            Header: 'Visits',
            accessor: 'visits',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )
 const MobileColumns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'COH',
            accessor: 'age',
            Cell: (props) => (
                <div className="color1">
                {numeral(props.value).format("$0,0.000")}
                </div>
        ),
          },
         
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(20), [])

  return (
  <>
    <div className="hide-mobile">
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </div>
    <div className="show-mobile">
      <Table columns={MobileColumns} data={data} />
   </div>
  </>

  )
}

export default App
```

I attempted to create a new file called Columns.js like so, but I can't use useMemo there it seems.

```
// Columns.js
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import numeral from "numeral";


    export const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'COH',
            accessor: 'age',
            Cell: (props) => (
                <div className="color1">
                {numeral(props.value).format("$0,0.000")}
                </div>
        ),
          },
          {
            Header: 'Visits',
            accessor: 'visits',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

export const MobileColumns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'COH',
            accessor: 'age',
            Cell: (props) => (
                <div className="color1">
                {numeral(props.value).format("$0,0.000")}
                </div>
        ),
          },

        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

};
```

Comment: You can't use hooks outside of the functional components. Why don't you just convert it into plain data without the useMemo, and when you import it in your component, stick that variable in the useMemo.

Comment: what about the numeral dependency ?

Comment: it looks like I can do something like this in Columns.js : `import numeral from "numeral";

export const columns =
 (() => [ ...etc `  and at the bottom `export default columns;`  but then importing it I'm still getting undefined : `import columns from "./Columns.js";`

Comment: column doesn't have to be a function. It can be constant. And you still can call numeral inside it. it would be created when the file is parsed the first time

Comment: I think I get it, but how do I import it into the App.js file?

Comment: just like you import anything else: ```import { columns } from './Columns'```

That should import the columns if you have it as a named import